# Can ColdFusion sessions be stored in dynamoDB?

Tags: session, coldfusion, amazon-dynamodb

Does anyone know if there's any way to get ColdFusion 10+ to store sessions in dynamoDB using the SDK?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest//DeveloperGuide/java-dg-tomcat-session-manager.html

http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx12CFK2FZ7PXRN/Amazon-DynamoDB-Session-Manager-for-Apache-Tomcat

Comment: I would say try it on one of your DEV servers and see if it works. Seems like it should.

Comment: Apparently someone has already created "A ColdFusion wrapper (i.e., a CFC) for the Amazon DynamoDB API." - https://github.com/bdcravens/cfdynamo

Comment: Have you given it a go? Did it work? If it didn't work, did you have difficulties, or did it seem to go OK but deliver unexpected results? Reading: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/12/need-help-know-how-to-ask-for-it.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK no, because `Session` scope can store any variables, whereas dynamoDB is a DB so variables have to be serialized first at least.  However, if your new or existing app does not reference session directly and use an abstration layer like [Coldbox's SessionStorage](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Plugins:SessionStorage.cfm) then you may still be able to do it, but I will then worry about the latency.